# Need help with example using enum in C++ programming

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this link http://wiki.ros.org/CppStyleGuide#Enumerations talk about using enum. But I haven't been able to use it correctly. Could you please show me an example how to use it?
Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230376/need-help-with-example-using-enum-in-c++-programming/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does this help?

```
namespace Choices
{
  enum Choice
  {
     Choice1,
     Choice2,
     Choice3
  };
}
typedef Choices::Choice Choice;

int foo() {
    Choice c = Choices::Choice1;

    switch(c) {
        case Choices::Choice1:
            // TODO: something
            break;
        case Choices::Choice2:
            // TODO: something
            break;
        case Choices::Choice3:
            // TODO: something
            break;
        default:
            // TODO: something
            break;
    }
}
```

(tested and compiles with gcc 4.8.4)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-03-29**:
Yes, it helps a lot. Thanks ahendrix.

But the correct should be `Choices::Choice c = Choices::Choice1;`

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-29**:
No; the `typedef Choices::Choice Choice` means that you should be able to use `Choice` as a type without requiring the `Choices::` namespace.

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-03-29**:
I am sorry, you are correct. I define the typedef wrong  so in declaring the variable I got an error which it didn't happen when I have the namespace. This makes me confused. Thank you very much :D